# Create a class MAT of size m x n

Tags: c++, oop, matrix

Create a class MAT of size m x n. Define the following matrix operations for MAT type objects

a.  Addition
b.  Subtraction
c.  Multiplication.

Comment: Is this homework? What are your own thoughts? In which programming language do you intend to implement it?

Comment: Why not call it Matrix? Does it have to be written in FORTRAN?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement the matrix as a class with array of arrays for the values. Addition and Substraction as well as Multiplication will be easily implemented according to the definition.